# How to make a dropdown menu with span tag and glyphicon instead of button on bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was looking for that a long time without success.

I found a [link](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/)  that explain how to do it, but it has no example and I don't know how to implement on my website.

Anyone can help me? Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code that you're looking for, that with jquery:

```
$('#willtoggle').on('click', function (event) {
    $("#toggled").toggle();
});
```

the #willtoggle is a span with the class of caret defined on bootstrap, so on click, it'll toggle the dropdown-menu(that have the id="toggled").

And this code for hiding it when clicking outside:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest('.dropdown').length === 0) {
      $("#toggled").hide();
  }
});
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/u4vn0y34/8/) that I made.

Comment: you can add this to your CSS for the cursor like the link example : `#willtoggle:hover,#willtoggletoo:hover{cursor:pointer;}`

Comment: Thank you about that @loli , check it out [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/u4vn0y34/2/)

Comment: The two clickable elements are span tags, and they're both clickable to toggle the menu, if you want that all of their area will be clickable, just you need to add them inside a div ,like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/u4vn0y34/3/) , is that what you're looking for?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. When I push on span tag, it show me all menus page. The one has two dropdowns, a button and a span tag.

If I push anywhere, that will show me every menu and I couldn't remove it.

[One picture][1]

[1]: http://es.tinypic.com/r/260u3qt/8

Comment: I saw your edited comment now, can you give me the code you're working on? You can put in jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SF1B9TBx

Sorry for disorder, it's not my fault. If it is not enough, tell me, please.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for to have? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/u4vn0y34/4/)

Comment: Ok , I've put an id for the menu that'll be toggled by the span, and changed the selector in the jquery code. Here's the new [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/u4vn0y34/5/)

Comment: That's really fine but I found a bug. When I press outside of menu, this not disappear however the button dropdown yes.

Comment: It tooks me some time to make the code work with no bug (normally, you can check if there's another one), so here's the link and i'll edit my answer as well : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/u4vn0y34/8/)

Comment: Sorry about this but... it doesn't work in my project, I only tried on JSFIDDLE and... when I tried on my web... it doesn't work... I don't know why... I'll give you my code (yours code). Sorry about all.

http://pastebin.com/0RLkiWFx

Comment: Do you include jquery in your project? And be careful , it's "toggled" not "toogled"

Comment: oh sorry... I'm so tired. It works fine right now, thank you very much for your help, your support and your infinite patience.

Comment: It's ok , these things always happens, no problem :)